# what will be OODesign for the following

Tags: java, oop

I was asked to finish this test in one of my interview and they wanted me to create classes intereface following all the right practices. I couldn't clear the interview but I sure am interested how you all experts out there would handle this.

Create an OODesign for the following scenario

There is a zoo, its has some animals.
Following are the animals which live in the zoo 
Lion
Tiger
Bear

Each animal has enerygy level

Every animal speaks, eats, play
by defalut when animal eat they gain +8 energy level
by default when animal play they loose -5 energy level
by defalut when animal speak they loose -1

By default each animal speak "Grrr..."
By default every animal when they play they say "I am loving it"

Only bear can dance but when bear dance he says "Look MA' I am dancing"

Following are the foods available for animals
Grain, Steak and salmon

When soundOff() method gets called on Zoo
every animal speak

When Tiger speaks it says "ROARR..."
When Lion speaks he says "Don't you dare ask me"

Comment: What is the code that you would use? And also, I already have a job.

Comment: That's what I am asking from people, i got the new job but i lost this one interview because something in my design they didn't like. I want to know how experts would design this. just classes and interfaces with method.

Comment: @OP Why not put YOUR design in, and let everyone pick holes in it

Comment: I wonder if they expected all interviewees not to chuckle at this question.

Comment: my design was Zoo interface, Animal abstract class with speak(), eat(), play(), getEnergyLevel(), setEnergylevel() methods with the properties energyLevel, I implemented the methods in the Animal class speak() where i printed system out grrrr... and same way for eat() and play() the default ones and then Tiger class extends Animal abstract class and implements Zoo interface which has method speakoff() so i override the methods speak, eat and play and implemented speakoff where i called the speak() method() of the tiger class.

Comment: same way other class lion and bear but i added a method can dance in Bear class. I created the contants in the zoo interface STEAK, SALMON and GRAIN

Comment: Wait your animals did implement the zoo interface? That sounds extremely strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would structure Zoo to contain a collection of the Animal base class to start with:

```
class Zoo {
 private Collection<Animal> animals;

 ...
 public void soundOff() {
  Iterator<Animal> i = animals.iterator();
  while( i.hasNext() )
   i.next().speak();
 }
```

then the Animal base class has the common methods/properties: speak, eat, play, energy level; also allow for the animal to reject food they don't like in the eat() method:

```
abstract class Animal {
 private int energyLevel;
 private String playMessage;
 private String speakMessage;

 ...
 public Animal(String speakMessage, String playMessage) {
  this.speakMessage = speakMessage;
  this.playMessage = playMessage;
 }

 public Animal() {
  this( "Grrr...", "I am loving it" );
 }
 ...
 public abstract void eat( Food f ) throws IllegalArgumentException;

 public void play() {
  System.out.println( playMessage );
  energyLevel += 8;
 }

 public void speak() {
  System.out.println( speakMessage );
  energyLevel -= 1;
 }
..
}
```

then you can have specialized classes -- like DancerAnimal:

```
abstract class DancerAnimal extends Animal {
 private String danceMessage;

 public DancerAnimal(String speakMessage, String playMessage, String danceMessage) {
  super( speakMessage, playMessage );
  this.danceMessage = danceMessage;
 }

 public DancerAnimal( String danceMessage ) {
   super();
   this.danceMessage = danceMessage;
 }

 public void dance() {
  System.out.println( danceMessage );
 }
...
}
```

based on this you can implement Bear:

```
class Bear extends DanceAnimal {
 public Bear() {
  super( "Look MA' I am dancing" );
 }
 ...
}
```

Lion and Tiger would just extend Animal base class and Food would probably be an enum.

My 2 cents on it.
Bear in mind that the above doesn't handle concurrency -- so one thread calling dance while the other calls play will corrupt the energyLevel -- but you can simply add a Lock around this.

Comment: Thanks Liv, So far I like the way you presented before i vote my answer i would like to see what others say

Comment: Isnt there any problem with having 2 methods with same name ? On animal class there are 2  void speak() .

Comment: well spotted! I've just edited the code to remove the duplicate one.

Answer (score 0):

Not all what you're looking for but something like this would help you to figure it out, d

eclare an animal class with all the properties and behavior common to all of them, then declare all the classes that define properties and behavior for each animal that extends the base class:

```
abstract class Animal
{
   private int energyLevel;

   public Animal(int eLevel)
   {
      setEnergyLevel(eLevel);
   }

   public void setEnergyLevel(int eLevel)
   {
       this.energyLevel = eLevel;
       if(energyLevel <= 0)
       {
          energyLevel = 0;
       }
   }

   public void speak()
   {
       System.out.println("grr...");
       setEnergyLevel(energyLevel - 1);
   }

   public void eat()
   {
       setEnergyLevel(energyLevel + 8);
   }

   public void play()
   {
       System.out.println("I'm loving it...");
       setEnergyLevel(energyLevel - 5);
   }
}


class Lion extends Animal
{
    public Lion(int energy)
    {
        super(energy);
    }
}

class Bear extends Animal
{
    public Bear(int energy)
    {
        super(energy);
    }

    public void dance()
    {
        System.out.println("I am dancing...");
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal
{
    public Tiger(int energy)
    {
        super(energy);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd really use inc/dec/set EnergyLevel functions so that you don't have to reuse your code (if < 0 lvl=0) everywhere.

Comment: thats sounds like a good idea as you would want change the energy leve of the particular animal

Comment: james_bond where is sounoff() method and Food GRAIN, STEAK, SALMON go

Answer (score 0):

```
class AnimalZoo {
       public int energyLevel=0;
       public String defaultVoice = "Grrr";
       public String sing = "I am lovinig t"; 

       public static void main(String [] args) {
        Tiger t = new Tiger();
        Lion l = new Lion();    
        Bear b = new Bear();

        AnimalZoo az = new AnimalZoo();
        az.soundOff();  
        }

       public void soundOff() {
        t.speak();
        l.speak();
        b.speak();
       }
       public void eat { 
          energyLevel+=8;
        }

       public void play{
          energyLevel-=5;
        } 

       public void speak { 
        energyLevel-=1;
        }
    }
    }

class Lion extends AnimalZoo {
    defaultVoice = "Don't you dare ask me";
    System.out.printnln(defaultVoice);
}

class Tiger extends AnimalZoo { 
    public void speak { 
        defaultVoice = "ROARR";
        System.out.println(defaultVoice);
    }
}

class Bear extends AnimalZoo {
         public void dance() {
    System.out.println("Look MA' I am dancing");

}
```

Comment: where did my comments go what i typed where i explained what i did

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    int energyLevel = ZooAnimalConstants.DEFAULT_ENERGY;
    String speakMessage;
    String playMessage;

    public Animal(int energy) {
        this.setEnergyLevel(energy);
        speakMessage="Grr...";
        playMessage="I am loving it";

    }

    public void setEnergyLevel(int energy) {
        if (energy < 0) {
            this.energyLevel = ZooAnimalConstants.DEFAULT_ENERGY;
        } else {
            this.energyLevel = energy;
        }
    }

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("speak message : "+speakMessage);
        this.setEnergyLevel(this.energyLevel - ZooAnimalConstants.MINUS_SPEAK_ENERGY);
    }

    public void eat() {
        this.setEnergyLevel(this.energyLevel + ZooAnimalConstants.ADD_EAT_ENERGY);
    }

    public void play() {
        System.out.println("play message : "+playMessage);
        this.setEnergyLevel(this.energyLevel - ZooAnimalConstants.MINUS_PLAY_ENERGY);
    }

    public int getEnergyLevel()
    {
        return this.energyLevel;
    }

}
```

Dance Behaviour:

```
public interface DanceBehaviour {

    public abstract void dance();

}

public class Bear extends Animal implements DanceBehaviour{

    public Bear() {
        super(ZooAnimalConstants.BEAR_DEFAULT_ENERGY);
    }

    public void dance()
    {
        System.out.println("Look MA' I am dancing");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Bear";
    }

}

public class Tiger extends Animal {

    public Tiger() {
        super(ZooAnimalConstants.TIGER_DEFAULT_ENERGY);
        super.speakMessage = "ROARR ..";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Tiger";
    }

}

public class Lion extends Animal {

    public Lion() {
        super(ZooAnimalConstants.LION_DEFAULT_ENERGY);
        this.speakMessage = "Don't you dare ask me";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Lion";
    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Zoo {

    ArrayList<Animal> listAnimal; 

    public Zoo()
    {
        listAnimal= new ArrayList<Animal>();
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        if(null != listAnimal && null != animal)
        {
            listAnimal.add(animal);
        }
    }

    public void soundOff()
    {
        for(Animal animal : listAnimal)
        {
            animal.speak();
        }
    }

    public void printAnimalEnergyReport()
    {
        for(Animal animal : listAnimal)
        {
            System.out.println("Energy Level for : "+animal.toString() + " : "+animal.energyLevel);
        }
    }

}

public interface ZooAnimalConstants {

        int DEFAULT_ENERGY=0;
        int ADD_EAT_ENERGY = 8;
        int MINUS_SPEAK_ENERGY = 1;
        int MINUS_PLAY_ENERGY = 5;

        int TIGER_DEFAULT_ENERGY=5;
        int LION_DEFAULT_ENERGY=6;
        int BEAR_DEFAULT_ENERGY=4;

}


public class ZooDemoMain {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Zoo myZoo = new Zoo();

        Animal tiger = new Tiger();
        Animal bear = new Bear();
        Animal lion = new Lion();

        myZoo.addAnimal(tiger);
        myZoo.addAnimal(lion);
        myZoo.addAnimal(bear);

        myZoo.soundOff();
        myZoo.printAnimalEnergyReport();

        bear.setEnergyLevel(0);

        if(bear.getEnergyLevel() == 0)
        {
            bear.eat();
            myZoo.printAnimalEnergyReport();
        }



    }

}
```